# C Setting bits issue

Tags: c

My code below is for an emergency text. So if `DU_Reason.bits.EmergencyDialIn` is set it will log into the network. Then if `send_update` is set it will send `Compose_Report()`. This is not a problem because send_update is cleared after the message is sent. But if tempalarm is set it will send a message and stay set unless it receives a message telling it to clear. This is to stop a message being sent constantly over and over when temp drops below limit. So if tempalarm has not been reset and if a leak is detected I want to only send the `Compose_Leak_Report();` but it sends `Compose_Temp_Report();` instead.

What is the way around doing this could anyone help.

```
if (DU_Reason.bits.EmergencyDialIn) {                       
    if (Send_Update) {
        Compose_Report();
        GSM_Send_Text_Sms (GSM_Tx_Buff, SenderNum);
        num_Leaks_month = 0;    
        monthly_timer = 0;
        Send_Update = 0;
        DU_Reason.bits.EmergencyDialIn = 0;
    } 
    else if (TempAlarm) {
        Compose_Temp_Report();
        GSM_Send_Text_Sms (GSM_Tx_Buff, SenderNum); 
        DU_Reason.bits.EmergencyDialIn = 0;
    } 
    else {
        Compose_Leak_Report();
        GSM_Send_Text_Sms (GSM_Tx_Buff, SenderNum); 
        DU_Reason.bits.EmergencyDialIn = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Vagish I should have known that, such a simple solution, I was totally over thinking it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am modifying your code by adding one more variable `TempAlarmTriggered` and initializing it with zero.

```
if (DU_Reason.bits.EmergencyDialIn) {                       
    if (Send_Update) {
        Compose_Report();
        GSM_Send_Text_Sms (GSM_Tx_Buff, SenderNum);
        num_Leaks_month = 0;    
        monthly_timer = 0;
        Send_Update = 0;
        DU_Reason.bits.EmergencyDialIn = 0;
    } 
    else if ((TempAlarm) && (TempAlarmTriggered == 0)) {
        TempAlarmTriggered  = 1;
        Compose_Temp_Report();
        GSM_Send_Text_Sms (GSM_Tx_Buff, SenderNum); 
        DU_Reason.bits.EmergencyDialIn = 0;
    } 
    else {
        Compose_Leak_Report();
        GSM_Send_Text_Sms (GSM_Tx_Buff, SenderNum); 
        DU_Reason.bits.EmergencyDialIn = 0;
    }
```

When your temp resets clear both `TempAlarmTriggered`  and `TempAlarm`.